# JMS and MQ (without JNDI)

Tags: java, xml, jms, mq

Created a webpage where a user can paste their XML file and after clicking the submit option, the XML file will go to other system ( which is test environment). That system is basically running on IBM (MQ) and I have to use JMS for it. I have QUEUE, Port, host name. Does anyone has any similar example which I can use as direction?

Comment: Provide a snippet of your code so someone could guide you

Comment: Please read about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.  Requests for code samples are off-topic on this site.  Try google if you are looking for tutorials regarding XML, JMS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is what you will need to do:

1. Accept the XML mesaage from UI.
2. Create a MQ Connection factory with details of your port,host and queue.
3. Create a JMS connection from MQ Connection Factory.
4. Create a  JMS session off the JMS connection.
5. Create a JMS message Producer off the JMS session.
6. Create a JMS TextMessage containing the XML file.
7. Send the message to the JMS queue via the producer.

Will try to add a code example in a while, in the meantime for each step you will be able to find multiple examples online.

Dont forget to close the JMS message producer, jms session and jms connection in the finally block as they are resources.

Comment: i have already created HTML page where i user can paste their XML code in TEXT box. Then i have done this. not sure what next......Create a connection factory 
         JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
         JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();                                                                                    //to create a Queue object  
         JmsQueue q1 = ff.createQueue("XYZ");

Comment: // Set the properties
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "lol");
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1410);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "wer");
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "abc");  out.println("</body></html>");
      } catch (JMSException ex) {
          out.println ("Error in HelloServletNew.doGet()... \n" + ex.toString());
           Logger.getLogger(HelloServletNew.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } finally {
         out.close();   what next. any idea.